# How to Curl PHP SpeakerDeck.com Oembed URL

Tags: php, curl, oembed

Could you please help me to Curl PHP speakerdeck.com oembed URL

I tried this, but it is returning anything.

```
<?php
$url='https://speakerdeck.com/oembed.json?url=http://www.speakerdeck.com/addyosmani/css-performance-tooling';
function get_data($url){
        $curl = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; en-US; rv:1.9.2.16) Gecko/20110319 Firefox/3.6.16");
        $curlData = curl_exec($curl);
        curl_close($curl);
        return $curlData;
    }


get_data($url);
?>
```

Comment: editing your question is fine but completely changing it means the people trying to help you need to debug it all over again.

Comment: try  echo get_data($url);  at the bottom.

Answer (score 1):

your code is working for me.  perhaps your question should be clearer.  do you mean you wish to grab the web page's contents?

this works if you want to grab the http return code(your code):

```
$url='https://speakerdeck.com/oembed.json?url=http://www.speakerdeck.com/addyosmani/css-performance-tooling';
$ch = curl_init(); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, TRUE); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, TRUE); // remove body 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE); 
$head = curl_exec($ch); 
$httpCode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE); 
print_r($httpCode);
curl_close($ch);
```

and if you want the web page contents:

```
$url='https://speakerdeck.com/oembed.json?url=http://www.speakerdeck.com/addyosmani/css-performance-tooling';
$ch = curl_init(); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, TRUE); 
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, TRUE); // remove body 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE); 
$page = curl_exec($ch); 
$httpCode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE); 
//you can do some error checking if you want here.
print_r($page);
curl_close($ch);
```

for your new code:

```
get_data($url);
```

try:

```
echo get_data($url);
```

Comment: For me no response is coming, the above code is returning 0

Comment: I copy-paste the exact code and I get a response.  Did you edit or copy-paste?

Comment: 1) ensure the commented line.  2) capture curl_exec return  3) print_r the correct variable(curl_exec return)

Comment: echo get_data($url); tried this page is blank no response

Comment: Is there any PHP version problem?

Comment: do a phpinfo(); and scroll down to see if you have the curl functions.  also, make sure display_errors is on so you can see errors.

Comment: I am able to curl for other URLs except KickStarter.com and speakerdeck.com

Comment: try the code(with suggested corrections) from another IP address...if you have been hitting them perhaps they shut you down? Like I said, my code works fine when copy-pasted exactly.